# How to disable camera feed while keeping LiDAR debug mesh?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm running an iOS14 ARSession on a LiDAR enabled device, and have it output the mesh overlay that it is dynamically creating over the camera feed.

**Is it possible to disable the camera feed for the ARView or ARSession, while still seeing the debug mesh overlay?**

Here's how I'm showing the mesh overlay:

```
arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)
```

What I want to see: black screen with colored lines representing mesh vertices and faces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to disable a camera feed while keeping only LiDAR debug mesh:

```
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

arView.environment.background = .color(.black)
```

...and if you need to get your camera feed back just use:

```
arView.environment.background = .cameraFeed()
```